# convert a text to url with dash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the code below. Now if I put some text in `pTitle` and when I press space from the keyboard it makes a `-` clone dash between words I typed. But the problem is after I press next word previous `-` dash removes also between `-` and word it also makes an auto space which I don't want. Now tell me how can I fix the `-` auto remove issue? Any advice? also, a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/739705/) attached for a quick check

Html:

```
pTitle: <input type="text" id='pTitle' name="fname"><br>
<br>
pUrl: <input type="text" id='pUrl' name="lname"><br>
```

Jq code:

```
$('#pTitle').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 32) {
                $('#pUrl').val($(this).val()+'-');
            } else {
                $('#pUrl').val($(this).val());
            }

            var charNumber = e.currentTarget.value.length;
            if (charNumber === 0) {
                $('#pUrl').val('#');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to replace spaces with dashes?
For example 'my cool link' should become 'my-cool-link'?

Comment: u r correct. can u answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a .replace() to swap the spaces for hyphens. The ternary equation allows the url to be "#" of the length of the input value == 0 (for example if you have text entered and then delete all characters) or the hyphenated text if there is text in the input.

```js
$('#pTitle').keyup(function (e) {
  var newVal = $(this).val();
  newVal.length == 0 
  ? $('#pUrl').val('#')
  : $('#pUrl').val(newVal.replace(/ /g,'-'));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
pTitle: <input type="text" id='pTitle' name="fname"><br>
<br>
pUrl: <input type="text" id='pUrl' name="lname"><br>
```

Comment: it  works in the snippet and in testing - there may be another issue with your code.

Comment: sorry - my fault - I changed val for newVal - will edit answer- have changed it now - it is fixed

Comment: Ok, also use `/ +/` or  `/\s+/` to removing continuously `-` in result

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is provided by **@gavgrif** above.
If you want to avoid regex, then here's a **non regex** solution

```js
$('#pTitle').keyup(function (e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val.length==0 
  ? $('#pUrl').val('#')
  : $('#pUrl').val(val.split(" ").join("-"));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
pTitle: <input type="text" id='pTitle' name="fname"><br>
<br>
pUrl: <input type="text" id='pUrl' name="lname"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read the text from `pTitle` input and replace space by dash character '-' and set the result into `pUrl` input

```js
$('#pTitle').keyup(function (e) {     
       $('#pUrl').val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,'-'));

       var charNumber = e.currentTarget.value.length;
       if (charNumber === 0) {
           $('#pUrl').val('#');
       }
  });
```